# Inserting data into two tables with foreign key to serial primary key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, common-table-expression, bulkinsert

I have a (large) data set in table `source` and would like to transform that data and place the result into two separate tables, `table_1` and `table_2`, where `table_2` references `table_1`. I'm looking for a solution that does not rely on any of the tables being empty, so I can't somehow choose my primary keys deterministically.

This is as far as I got:

```sql
-- Example data. This will actually be a complex query.
create temporary table source
as select * from (values ('hello', 'world'), ('foo', 'bar')) as t(data_1, data_2);

-- Tables into which to insert the data.
create temporary table table_1(id serial primary key, data text);
create temporary table table_2(id serial primary key, table_1_id int references table_1, data text);

with
    inserted_rows as (
        insert into table_1(data)
        select source.data_1
        from source
        returning id as table_1_id, source.data_2 as data_2)
insert into table_2(table_1_id, data)
select table_1_id, data_2
from inserted_rows;
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

```
psql:captain/panel/migrations/0239_daily_billing_step_1_test.sql:17: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "source"
LINE 6:         returning id as table_1_id, source.data_2 as data_2)
```

I understand what it's saying, but it seems that this makes it impossible to access bot the generated primary key of the `insert` in the CTE as well as the columns from `source` at the same time.

Comment: And before someone suggests joining `inserted_rows` with `source` again on `data_1`, ChatGPT already tried to sell me that, but it won't work, because `data_1` has duplicates.